# Qt - What is meant by this sentence

Tags: qt, widget, clipped

At the following web page: http://web.mit.edu/qt-dynamic/www/tutorials-tutorial-t3.html

The following sentence is mentioned:

`A widget is clipped by its parent and by the widgets in front of it.`

What do we mean by such sentence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Qt has the concept of parent/child widgets. The parent widget is the container of the child widget, all the way up to the main window widget. So this is just saying that a widget will be clipped by its parent (container) widget. This means it won't extend past its parent's boundaries, but will be cut off if it goes beyond. Likewise, a widget is clipped by any widgets in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

First off: the second part of the sentence is no longer true for Qt >= 4.1 where a parent *may* paint behind its children.

In graphics, *clipping* describes the limiting of the painting to a given area. E.g. if you drew a line from `(0,0)` to `(100,100)` with a clipping rectangle of `(50x50)@(0,0)`, you'd effectively draw a line only from `(0,0)` to `(50,50)`, ie. all pixels that would have been painted, but lay outside the clipping region, were discarded.

In Qt, painting can [optionally be clipped](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qpainter.html#clipping) using [`QPainter`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qpainter.html) methods, but the painting is always implicitly clipped by the [`QPaintDevice`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qpaintdevice.html) you're operating on. [`QWidget`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html) is a `QPaintDevice`, and as such, painting outside of its [`QWidget::rect()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#rect-prop) will have no effect (= it will be clipped to `rect()`).

Now, about the second part of the sentence: In older Qt versions, the child widgets would first fill their area with the background color/image, thus effectively clipping the parent's painting to outside the union of all children's geometries. Since Qt 4.1, this behaviour can be disabled by setting the [`QWidget::autoFillBackground`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property to `false`. Indeed, this happens to be the new default, too.

In the `autoFillBackground == false` case, the child widgets do no longer erase the parent's drawing acting as their background, except where they actually paint. Take a [`QLabel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qlabel.html) as an example: with `autoFillBackground == false`, it merely paints its text, leaving the parent's drawing to shine through as the label's background.